# Which word can I use to refer to pictures on the backside of the book covers?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Which word or words can I use to refer to picture on the opposite side of the book cover? I.e. in hardcover bock each double page/broadside behind the hardcover can have a picture on it. Is there a single word to refer these parts of book?

There is a [list of book terms macmillandictionary.com](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/parts-of-books), but I didn't find any term for this there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pages themselves and the pages opposite them are known as **endpapers**.

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/endpaper):

> **endpaper**
>
> noun, Bookbinding.
>
> 1. a sheet of paper, often distinctively colored or ornamented, folded vertically once to form two leaves, one of which is pasted flat to the
>      inside of the front or back cover of a book, with the other pasted to
>      the inside edge of the first or last page to form a flyleaf.
>
> Also called end leaf, end sheet.

The illustrations (where there are any) are normally just accredited under Illustrations: Front Cover ... / *Front Endpaper* ... / ...; one could use 'front endpaper illustration/s' etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems to be exact word I looked for. Though as I wanted to refer to endpapers which is behind front cover and back cover, and distinguish between them, I guess I have to use something like "front cover endpaper" and "back cover endpaper" in this case...